# Unfortunately Deleted /usr/bin/python

Tags: command-line, apt, python, symbolic-link

Unfortunately I deleted the `/usr/bin/python` in my ubuntu 12.04 
I went to /usr/bin/ and run

> ls -al

then I got

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      64 Jul 13 14:58 python -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python
```

How do I link that python so that I can get python in terminal on running `python`

I also reinstalled python by

```
apt-get --purge --reinstall install python
```

I tried adding sym link like 
`ln -s  /usr/lib/python2.7/ /usr/bin/python` then it thrown in `ln: failed to create symbolic link`/usr/bin/python': File exists`

Comment: What? "python -> /Library/Frameworks.." Looks like a Mac OS X path. How did you get that there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Boot up in recovery mode or something. I guess your current system state won't make it to the GUI without Python.
2. Remove the current dead link.

   ```
   rm /usr/bin/python
   ```
3. Recreate the link

   ```
   ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
   ```

Don't forget to prepend the commands with `sudo` if you aren't root at that point.

Comment: This is really helpful, it saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following commands:

```
sudo unlink /usr/bin/python                     #to delete the previous symbolic link
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/bin/python   #to recreate the new correct symbolic link
```